# Yii2: How to access a table column via a relation

Tags: yii2

I have two tables, `dpd` and `cabang`. One `cabang` can only have one `dpd` and each `cabang` should have a `dpd`.

This is the relation in my "Cabang" model :

```
public function getIdDpd()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Dpd::className(), ['id_dpd' => 'id_dpd']);
}
```

I try to access "dpd" attribute in "dpd" table in my view, I tried to var_dump it but still got the same error :

```
$model = Cabang::find()
        ->joinWith('idDpd')
        ->all();

var_dump($model->dpd);
```

**Note : `'dpd'` in `var_dump($model->dpd)` refered to the column name in `'Dpd'` table. I have a column name `'dpd'` in my `'dpd'` table. I also tried `$model->idDpd->dpd` but it return the same error.**

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is

```
$model->dpd
```

where you are trying to access it assuming that `$model` has the `Dpd` object, but it is holding the `Cabang` object and you should use the relation name to get the `Dpd` object and then call the field name like below.

```
$model->idDpd->dpd
```

**EDIT: You are using `->all()` in your query not `->one()` and hence you cannot simply do `$model->idDpd->dpd` right after the query, you need to loop through the records and then call the relation, i thought you might be doing the same way but anyway see below how to use it.**

```
$cabangs = Cabang::find()
        ->joinWith('idDpd')
        ->all();

foreach($cabangs as $index=>$model){
    $model->idDpd->dpd;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried using $model->idDpd->dpd as I had mentioned at the end of my post, but still I got the same error

Comment: It works, thanks! I'm still learning, if you don't mind could you explain what does `$index=>$model` do in the loop? Why don't we just use `foreach($cabangs as $model)` instead? What is the purpose of $index?

Comment: @codejunkie yes, you can use just `foreach($cabangs as $model)` when using `$index=>$model` means we are referring the `key` of the array as `$index` which in your case will be a numeric index starting from 0. but if you have just one row like `['column_name_1'=>'column_value_1','column_name_2'=>'column_value_2']` and you want to print the name of the column along with the value you can do `foreach($cabangs as $key=>$value){ echo "column name is $key and column value is $value";}` read moer here https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thank you very much once again for helping me solved the problem! I've stuck with it for days